# What is the best way to preload a binary (zip) in html

Tags: html, service-worker, preload

I'm trying to preload a file that's around 15MB big. The way it should work is this:

1. A user accesses example.com/
2. The big file is asynchronously downloaded and cached
3. When the user visits example.com/app, this cached file is used

For context the file I'm trying to download is a webgl binary, loading and caching it on / should make opening /app a little faster on slow connections.

I'm unsure however, what the best approach could be, I've tried

```
<link
    rel="preload"
    href="https://link-to-file.com/file"
    as="fetch"
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
 />
```

But this doesn't seem to work and downloads a file of type octet-stream instead:
[image]

[image]

Another approach I think could work is installing service worker that downloads and caches the file when it is installed. If it's possible to preload instead that would obviously be easier.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you checked whether the file to be downloaded (which uses a completely different URL in your example) sends proper caching headers?

Comment: @NicoHaase what do you mean with proper caching headers? what would be incorrect? I've updated the post

Comment: Could you explain more about how your `https://example.com/app` "uses" the `https://link-to-file.com/file`? I.e. what is it on that page that ends up reading the subresource, and what's the mechanism for providing the reference to that subresource?

Comment: Thank you for your help I just answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <link
  rel="preload"
  href="https://example.com/resource.zip"
  as="fetch"
  type="application/octet-stream"
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
 />
```

After trying out different ways this is what worked for me. The type seems to be the important bit here.